# iOS 10 UNNotificationAction Open App from Background

Tags: ios, notifications, action, application-lifecycle, usernotifications

How can I open my app, when user receive notification and my app was in background? Of course tap on notification itself would open app, but how to handle it with custom notification action?

I have implemented UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate and userNotificationCenter(_, didReceive, ...) already

Just need a code which would open my app and do specific action (for example go to specific view)

It would be nice if notification handler recognise that notification and open iPhone app or Apple Watch app depends on where action was tapped..

Comment: Further to this question and the suggested answers, I note that https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationactionoptions/1648192-foreground says: "Use this option for actions that require the user to interact further with your app. Do not use this option simply to bring your app to the foreground."

Any ideas what distinction this is making and why it matters?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok i have found the solution. We have to set UNNotificationActionOptions :)

```
UNNotificationActionOptions.foreground
```

Answer (score 12):

A Swift 3/4 example (because I did not know how to set this option): important are the `UNNotificationActionOptions` of the `UNNotificationAction`.

```
let myAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "myActionIdentifier", title: "MyAction", options: [.foreground])
```